# R data.table 1.9.2 issue on setkey

Tags: r, data.table

It seems to be a bug introduced post 1.8.10 related to setkey with DT which contains lists.
Run two below codes to see the issue:

```
library(data.table)
dtl <- list()
dtl[[1]] <- data.table(scenario = 1,
                       processing = c(function(x) x))
dtl[[2]] <- data.table(scenario = 2,
                       processing = c(function(x) x))
dt <- rbindlist(dtl)
setkeyv(dt, c("scenario"))
```

and second below, currently produce error:

```
dtl <- list()
dtl[[1]] <- data.table(scenario = 2, # <- note we change order
                       processing = c(function(x) x))
dtl[[2]] <- data.table(scenario = 1,
                       processing = c(function(x) x))
dt <- rbindlist(dtl)
setkeyv(dt, c("scenario")) #setkey cannot sort?
```

It was working well in 1.8.10. I'm not able to setkey on my DT, seems to be related to DT which contains list of functions. Any easy workaround? I track the error msg to C code but have no idea how to fix it.

R 3.0.2 + data.table 1.9.2 on windows 64bit
Thanks

Comment: an "easy workaround" follows from your code comment; if setkey can't sort, don't try to sort with it: `dt <- dt[order(scenario)];setkey(dt, scenario)`

Comment: I think this is a reproducible example of bug [#5366](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=975&func=detail&aid=5366). It can be reproduced even more simply with `dt <- data.table(a=2:1,b= list(list(1),list(2))); setkeyv(dt,'a')`

Comment: thank both of you.
GSee, the simple fix is working, even on bigger dt and more keys.
 
mnel, indeed it is the same error, I don't know why it has such low priority.
 
Matt, can we higher the priority of #5366 to have it handled in the next release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This is now fixed in commit #1216 of v1.9.3 (the current development version). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=datatable&revision=1216):

> `setkey` doesn't allow list columns as keys. However, a bug in `setkey` did not allow setting key on `data.table` *just containing* list columns. This is now fixed. Closes #5366. Thanks to James Sams for reporting and to Michael Nelson for pinpointing the issue with a minimal reproducible example. Also thanks to MusX for [reporting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186798/r-data-table-1-9-2-issue-on-setkey).

We should be pushing 1.9.4 (next stable release) to CRAN sometime soon.

Comment: Great! thanks for so fast reaction, I didn't even put yet the presorting workaround in all the places in my code.