# Is it possible to include >=, <= operators when using setkey with data.table in R?

Tags: r, function, data.table, package

I'm looking at this brief tuto for data.table

```
https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-data-table-tutorial-with-50-examples/
```

but I get stuck when the author talks about `setkey()`

I will put my example. I work with iris database so it can be easy replicated

```
mydata <- as.data.table(iris)

#Change variable names
mydata <- setnames(mydata, c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), 
c("sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "species"))
```

Now I will use a factor variable and a numeric variable as keys:

```
setkey(mydata, species, petal_length)
```

Using this works perfectly:

```
> mydata[.("setosa", 1.4)]
    sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width species
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
 3:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
 4:          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
 5:          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
 6:          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
 7:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
 8:          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2  setosa
 9:          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
10:          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1  setosa
11:          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
12:          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
13:          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

But this throws an error:

```
mydata[.("setosa", <1.4)]
Error: inesperado '<' in "mydata[.("setosa", <"
```

So my question is if it is possible to include >, <, >=, <= when searching using `setkey` because that function is supposed to work on variables of any type. If yes, what will be the correct form to call something such as `mydata[.("setosa", <1.4)]`

I looked at:

[R data.table setkey with numeric column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854476/r-data-table-setkey-with-numeric-column)

[R data.table 1.9.2 issue on setkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186798/r-data-table-1-9-2-issue-on-setkey)

but found nothing useful to answer my question.

I also read `data.table` documentation but there are no useful examples.

Any comment will be much appreciated.

Comment: you appear to be trying a non-equi join, search a bit for that

Comment: Yes, you were right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found somethig that can be useful using `seq` function.

Suppose I want to retrieve the observations for setosa which have between petal_length from 1.4 to 2.

Following the example in my original question, we can use:

```
na.omit(mydata[.("setosa", seq(1.4,2, 0.1))])
```

Which returns the observations we wanted.

```
seq(1.4, 2, 0.1)
```

returns a sequence from 1.4 to 2 by 0.1 steps. This looks for values in the data.table and generates observations for 1.6, 1.8 and 1.9 which are NA. That's why the first function which is called is `na.omit`

Hope this can be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 1):

It appears like you are subsetting rather than extracting identical matches. THe below feels more like the natural syntax

```
mydata[species=="setosa" & petal_length < 1.4]
```

or a non-equi join like this

```
mydata[.(species="setosa", i.petal_length=1.4), on=.(species, petal_length < i.petal_length)]
```

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. The point here is that I'm exploring how does setkey() work.